# MateriaUI don't target attribute onclick with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

here is my situation,

materiaul UI don't target my attribute on click.

I have this button:

```
<FlatButton       
containerElement="button"
className="selectedNumberOfPeopleButton"
onClick={this.selectedNumberOfPeople} 
value="1"
label="Default" />
```

which should return the value in the console as it does work with any other bootstrap or custom button such as:

```
    <Button color="danger" className="selectedNumberOfPeopleButton" onClick={this.selectedNumberOfPeople} value="1">Danger!</Button>
```

or

```
<button className="selectedNumberOfPeopleButton" onClick={this.selectedNumberOfPeople} value="1">
          1
        </button>
```

I can see in the React dev tool it certainly due because the `onclick` is not being in the same element as the value, see screenshot:

[image]

we can see the `onclick` of the `flatbutton` is not in the same element has the value . . . compare the button above which works

How can i make this work, to have my `onclick` targeting my button value using Material UI ?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`value` is a reserved attribute name and is not valid for `<button>`.
Since it is not recognized, you must refer to it using `e.target.getAttribute('value')`.
Or try to find another name.

**[Value Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_value.asp) - Here is some information on 'value' attribute**

**[React Froms](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html) - Here is a good practice of using 'value' attribute in React**